# How to convert a string column which contains date and time into just date using sql cast operator?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a column called 'created_date' whose **data type is string**. It contains records that are of the pattern date and time. I want to create another column called 'modified_date' that will take just the date from the 'created_date' column so as to be able to do some mathematical computations on dates later. I want to do this using the **SQL CAST** operator.

Below is how I expect the output to be-

```
ID        created_date         modified_date
1      2017-11-01 16:30:40     2017-11-01
2      2017-11-23 15:30:40     2017-11-23
3      2017-11-16 14:30:40     2017-11-16
```

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: Please tag your question ONLY with the database you are using.  Which is it?  MySQL or BigQuery?

Comment: BigQuery it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to assume that you are using BigQuery.

You can use:

```
select date(created_date)
```

You could also be more specific:

```
select date(substr(created_date, 1, 10))
```

Or convert to a `datetime` and then to a `date`:

```
select date(cast(created_date as datetime))
```

Comment: Thanks! Just for my information-CAST operator doesn't work in BigQuery? @GordonLinoff

Comment: @user11035754 . . . I tested all three of these in BigQuery -- although I clearly mistyped what I intended for the third one.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple date_format() and str_to_date()

```
select date_format(str_to_date(created_date,'%Y-%m-%d %T'), '%Y-%m-%d') modified_date
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT *, DATE(TIMESTAMP(created_date)) modified_date
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

> I want to do this using the SQL CAST operator.

Note: i do not recommend using generic CAST for DATE, DATETIME, TIMESTAMP data types. Instead you should use respective functions as in this answer. Or if string is not directly represent such datatypes - you can use respective PARSE_ function where you can set format in which date/datetime/timestamp is represented in string!